# Access description field for file in a view

Tags: 7, views, files

Gents, I have two fields that accept multiple file uploads.  One of those fields has file descriptions enabled.  I need to access those field descriptions in my view, but I don't see the file description field popping up in the list of available file fields.

I've added the relationship fid for the field that has multiple files associated with it.

So, I'm confused as to how I'm supposed to get the file description view exposed.  How do I do so?

Let me know if I need to clarify further.

[image: list of file fields available in view]

[image: views config]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the file description to display by adding your file field (just as Content: fieldname), then choosing to 'Rewrite Results'. For the Replacement Text, there is an option to use [field_fieldname-description].

Reference: http://drupal.org/node/1128270#comment-5253600

Answer (score 0):

It does not show up when you are choosing the field in your view but it will once you choose the file field itself and see your preview. (see my screen capture.)[image: Access description field for file in a view]. This is all assiming you enabled "descriptions" in the content type field itself but you implied you have already done that.

Does this help?